# Как исправить ошибку поиска элемента с помощью find для вектора из элементов класса?

Tags: c++, stl

Нужно обновить данные у элемента вектора. Для этого использую функцию `find` и сравниваю по `find_id`, но компилятор выдаёт ошибку:

> ...xutility(5112,21): error C2676: бинарный "==": "Solder" не определяет этот оператор или преобразование к типу приемлемо к встроенному оператору

```
...xutility(5147): message : выполняется компиляция ссылки на экземпляр шаблон функции "_InIt
 std::_Find_unchecked1<_InIt,_Ty>(_InIt,const _InIt,const _Ty
 &,std::false_type)"
with 
1>        [ 
1>           
1>            _InIt=Solder *, 
1>            _Ty=find_id 
1>        ]
```

После найденного элемента мы через его метод обновляем для него данные. Класс солдата сократил и оставил только нужное. В классе группы, `values` - это вектор с номерами, которые являются полем в классе `Solders` и именем `number`.

```
class Solder
{
private:
    int counterForUpdate;
    string* name;
public:
    int number;
     //конструктор
    Solder(string name_in = "Неизвестно", int number_in = 0)
    {
        name = new string(name_in);
        number = number_in;
    }
    void update(int counter){
        counterForUpdate = counterForUpdate + counter;
    }
};

struct find_id : std::unary_function<Solder, bool> {
    int number;
    find_id(int id) :number(number) { }
    bool operator()(Solder const& ms) const {
        return ms.number == number;
    }
};

class Group
{
private:
    std::vector<Solder> solders;
public:
    void addSolder(string name, int number)
    {
        Solder newSolder(name, number);
        solders.push_back(newSolder);
    }

    void updateStates(int count, int result, std::vector<int> values)
    {
        std::vector<Solder>::iterator it;
        for (vector<Solder>::size_type i = 0; i != count; i++)
        {
            it = std::find(solders.begin(), solders.end(), find_id(values[i]));
            if (result == 0)
            {
                it->update(0);
            }
            else
            {
                it->update(2);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: `std::find` принимает третьим параметром объект типа, которое хранит итерируемый объект. Может использовать `std::find_if`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала — точно `find_id(int id) :number(number) { }`? Не `find_id(int id) :number(id) { }`? :)

Ну, а по делу... `find` принимает *значение*, с которым сравнивает элементы. Вы же предлагаете не значение, а функтор-предикат.

Может, вы перепутали и вместо `find_if` написали `find`? Попробуйте с `find_if`...

Comment: Точно, благодарствую. Который раз выручаете ламера в с++ :)